# How to implement if else and else if in ADF dynamic expression

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

How can I achieve below conditions in ADF dynamic expression:

**if variable=a  then A

if variable=b then B

else C**

I'm able to achieve only true or false condition in IF but here I want to verify multiple conditions. No switch case function available in adf dynamic expression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [if](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#if) function in Azure Data Factory's (ADF) [expression language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#logical-functions) only supports one true or false condition and no switch function but you just have to nest them.  Use the `equals` function for value comparison.  Something like this:

```
@if(equals(variables('varInput'), 'a'), 'Ax', if(equals(variables('varInput'), 'b'), 'Bx', 'C'))
```

Comment: i am not able to understand above the condition, please help me. i want to check condition based my activity output to setup true or false based if condition.. like if(A==1) or if (B==2)

Comment: Hi @wBob what you mean by AX and BX is it after matched record , we have to consider its the right value and C is the both condition not matched we can put in C..is it my understanding is correct. kindly help me.